# Extracting data from querystring

Tags: php, string, split, query-string

I want to be able to see which type of action that a user did and on which product. Below you can see how the query string looks like and what I want is to extract (in this case) "changeInfo" and "2".

Below is my code for splitting the query string, which works but I apparently "split" is deprecated, and shouldn't be used. So, what can I use instead? What is the best way to extract these values?

```
//$queryString = index.php?action=changeInfo&id=2

list($a, $action, $b, $id) = split('[=&]', $queryString);

echo "$a, $action, $b, $id";    //action, changeInfo, id, 2
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$quertString = parse_url("index.php?action=changeInfo&id=2",PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str("action=changeInfo&id=2",$quertString);
var_dump($quertString);
```

Output

```
array
  'action' => string 'changeInfo' (length=10)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
```

If you want to break it further

```
list($a,$b) = array_keys($quertString);
list($action,$id) = array_values($quertString);


var_dump($a, $action, $b, $id);
```

Answer (score 1):

split() was replaced by explode(), in case that comes in handy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does. "apparent split() is deprecated" is what the author said, and one possible solution for the existing code is to replace it using explode(). His code already works.